# SQL Role still present after uninstalling from SQL 2014 Failover Cluster (WFC)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, failovercluster

I am trying to install a 3 node Active-Active-Active SQL WFC. One of the SQL role IPs we had set aside was actually already in use. Originally, once I received the message, I tried removing the role by running the "Remove node from a SQL Server failover cluster" in the Maintenance page of the SQL Server Installation Center. The uninstall completed, but the role is still there, and now when I attempt to run the Removal again, when I get to the "Cluster Node Configuration" step, the "SQL Server instance name:" dropdown doesn't provide any instances.

I wanted to know what the best steps would be to remove this role? Can I remove it through Failover Cluster Manager without harming future SQL role setups? Can I try re-installing with the same information and then uninstalling again when it inevitably fails? Can I change the DNS so that the IP matches the Network name that we've provided it?

Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: can you also share some screenshots and try to  reframe the question with more details.I have voted to migrate to DBA.SE

Comment: I can't due to the nature of the environment. I can tell you that under the resources tab for this SQL Server role, the server name is offline and under Other Resources, the IP address shows as offline and <not configured>. I know I've seen other SQL WFC questions on this exchange before, but I'm obviously okay with it getting to the right place to be answered.

Comment: imagine yourself in the same position trying to answer the same question,will this info be sufficient.try providing cluster log

Comment: I do understand, and if I could export from this environment, I would. Is there anything in particular you would be looking for in the log? Anything I can ctrl+f that I might be able to summarize?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clustering/2012/05/07/how-to-troubleshoot-create-cluster-failures-in-windows-server-2012/